# Modifing a list created in constructor | Java

Tags: java, list, class, constructor

I'm doing an exercise from a course. The exercise tells me:

-create a 'Calculator' class

-Each new object of this class should have String list, where will be an operation's history stored (list created in the constructor). The constructor cannot have any parameters.

And of course basic operations in calculator.

So I've started to create this, and that's what I've got now:

```
class Calculator {

    public Calculator () {
        List<String> history = new LinkedList<String>();
    }

    public double add(double num1, double num2) {
        history.add("added " + num1 + " to " + num2);     //here's the problem
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

But when I try to add the new string to the history list, I can't do that, because it doesn't exist in that place of the program.

Wouldn't it be better to create a List not in the constructor, but directly in the class?

Even if it would, I should do this exercise the way they tell me to do, so could you help me and show how to add something to the List which is created in the constructor?

Comment: Hey! You can tell your instructor to write more precise requirements. You are probably supposed to *define* the list in the constructor but *declare* it as an object attribute.

Comment: Think so, too... You can make it a `private List<String> history;` and just initialize it in the constructor. Then you can `add` values in a different method of that class.

Comment: I bet it's that, because your requirement *Each new object of this class should have String list, where will be an operation's history stored (list created in the constructor). The constructor cannot have any parameters.* does **not explicitly say the list has to be narrowed down to constructor scope**. It's not the object having that list, it's currently the object's constructor exclusively.

Comment: Thank you guys :) That's how I'll do.

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to the fact that `add()` is trying to fetch `history` which **happens to be a local variable** inside constructor and **as local vars have no scope outside its method**, `add()` will not be able to reach that.

So in order to fix this, modify like the field `history` at class level so that all of it's method can reach out to it. It can be initialized inside the constructor and can very well be used inside the class. Based on the visibility it can be `public | private | protected`. Your code might look like,

```
class Calculator {

    private List<String> history;

    public Calculator () {
        history = new LinkedList<String>();
    }

    public double add(double num1, double num2) {
        history.add("added " + num1 + " to " + num2);
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are fully ignoring that the OP is aware of that. The question asks about something else.

Comment: Yes, OP might aware of that, but as I could get OP' s que as 'But when I try to add the new string to the history list, I can't do that, because it doesn't exist in that place of the program... I should do this exercise the way they tell me to do, so could you help me and show how to add something to the List which is created in the constructor'

Hence I suggested..

Comment: Fair enough, but then please add a little more explanation *why* it doesn't work in his current state and *why* he has to declare the list as an object attribute. I think you'd agree that just adding (the obvious/trivial) `private List<String> history;` as the whole answer should not be the Stack Overflow standard.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the scope problem here. Thanks for explanation, I'll make it that way :)

Answer (score 0):

Using oop concepts like inheritance the code could be rewrite like:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Calculator extends LinkedList<String>
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calculator c = new Calculator();
        System.out.println(c.add(1,2));
        System.out.println(c.getFirst());
    }
    
     public Calculator () {
           
     }

     public double add(double num1, double num2) {
            this.add("added " + num1 + " to " + num2);     //here's the problem
            return num1 + num2;
     }
}
```

Output:

```
3.0
added 1.0 to 2.0
```